# How to pass the parameters properly for a callback function for preg_replace_callback using a preexisting function?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, legacy

I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)......... eval()'d code on line 2 Since removing e from the regex expression ~<IF (.*?)(?<!-)>(.*?)~se as shown in the line below  because it became deprecated.

```
$template['template_html'] = preg_replace('~<IF (.*?)(?<!\-)>(.*?)</IF>~se', '$this->get_templates_callback(\'\\1\', \'\\2\', $template[\'template_name\'])', $template['template_html']);
```

I understood I need to use preg_replace_callback() and rewrite using an anonymous function however I am running into troubles rewriting it as $this->get_templates_callback() needs to be called and executed as well.

```
    function get_templates_callback($condition, $code, $piece)
{
    $macro_id = isset($this->macro[$piece]) ? count($this->macro[$piece]) : 0;
    $this->macro[$piece][$macro_id] = '$macro_replace[' . $macro_id . '] = ((' . $condition . ') ? "' . $code . '" : ""); ';
    return '{' . chr(36) . 'macro_replace[' . $macro_id . ']}';
}
```

How should I properly go about properly passing parameters into this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`use statement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-179) to pass additional parameters.

```
function (array $matches) use ($condition, $code, $piece)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to pass in $matches as an array.

Comment: $matches array is passed by preg_replace_callback, all your other parameters are passed with use statement.